# Wrong splitting string (split(" "))

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have some text, for example:

```
String text = "I have some a good text".
String[] s = text.split(" ");
```

and I have such result:

```
s[0] - I have,
s[1] - some,
s[2] - a good,
s[3] - text
```

Why splitter don't split text, when between space (" ") 2 or 1 symbols ("I     have" and "a good"), and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this your actual code? Besides the `.` where a `;` should be, it works just fine, and produces a 6-element array as expected.

Comment: I assume you are talking about Java. I checked your code and the split works as expected.

Comment: Checked with C# as well https://ideone.com/56W5dk, working well

Comment: It can't be.. Something is fishy...

Comment: You might have a "special space" in the string (like &#160)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, the split method takes a regex as a parameter. As such, I'd recommend splitting by any white space:

```
text.split("\\s");
```

That way, even if you use a different non-printable whitespace in the text, it will get split.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html